# UI ignores the boolean from the checkbox

Tags: c#, wpf, checkbox, data-binding, xceed

Consider the following scenario:

-You have a tabbed interface and it has four tabs.

-You put a few components and you bind them like this:

```
<TextBox x:Name="LocationBackup" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Height="29" Margin="0,51,0,0"
                             TextWrapping="Wrap" VerticalAlignment="Top" Width="505"
                             Text="{Binding Source={x:Static properties1:Settings.Default},
                           Path=AutoBackupLocation}"
                             TextChanged="LocationBackup_TextChanged" IsEnabled="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=AutoBackupCheckbox, FallbackValue=False, TargetNullValue=False}"
```

In this scenario, if the components aren't in the first tab, data binding fails.

Comment: You are trying to bind to a "SlotSelectCheckbox". Where is this control defined and where is the IntegerUpDown defined. The binding will fail if they reside in different naming scopes.

Comment: All of them are in the same window, on the same tab (the program uses a tabbed interface.

Comment: Well, please update your question to clarify this then: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: OK. I've added some extra info (along with something that I noticed just now).

Comment: Didn't you read the link? You need to provided a *reproducible* sample of your issue if you want anyone to be able to help you.

Comment: Replaced the XAML with something that is easier to debug. These are the least bit of code where the bug is caused.

Comment: "Easier to debug"? Your issue is not reproducible.

Comment: Can you please elaborate? I don't know what exactly do you need. The entire source code? The xaml file? Can you at least show me an example?

Comment: I already did...look at the link I provided. In there you will find all information you need about how to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: OK. I think I figure out how the bug is triggered. I re-wrote the enite question.

Comment: I don't see a question. But you can't bind to an element in another tab using ElementName.

Comment: How can I bind them, then?

Comment: Read up on MVVM: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh848246.aspx